Change location of user defined odbc
BY default "USER DATA SOURCES" must be $HOME/.odbc.ini, But in a newly built RHEL8 server is showing the below result. Is its possible to update the "USER DATA SOURCES" location as $HOME/.odbc.ini
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /etc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8


(Off: The relevant function is _odbcinst_UserINI.c:_odbcinst_UserINI called from odbcinst.c:PrintConfigInfo) On: does getent passwd $USER or ls -ld ~ show any non-usual?
